# Find and replace a text in a XML file between two placeholders with a placeholder having special characters

Tags: sed

I have a requirement mentioned below.

Sample file.txt ::

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="${shutdown.port}" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

<Listener className="com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener"
        port="${jmx.port}"
        bind="127.0.0.1"
        useSSL="false"
        passwordFile="${catalina.base}/conf/jmxremote.password"
        accessFile="${catalina.base}/conf/jmxremote.access"
        authenticate="true"/>

<Listener className="com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.deploy.TcContainerDeployer" />

 <GlobalNamingResources>

 <Resource
       name="jdbc/myDBPool1"
       auth="Container"
       type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
       description="Oracle Datasource"
       factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
       url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:<dbanme>"
       user="myusername"
       password="somepassword1"
       validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
 />


 <Resource
       name="jdbc/myDBPool2"
       auth="Container"
       type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
       description="Oracle Datasource"
       factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
       url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:<dbanme>"
       user="myusername"
       password="somepassword2"
       validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
/>   

<Resource
           name="jdbc/myDBPool3"
           auth="Container"
           type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
           description="Oracle Datasource"
           factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
           url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:<dbanme>"
           user="myusername"
           password="somepassword3"
           validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
/>

 </GlobalNamingResources>

 <Service name="Catalina">

 <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="tomcat-http--" maxThreads="300" minSpareThreads="50"/>

 <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="${http.port}"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="${https.port}"
           acceptCount="100"
           maxKeepAliveRequests="15"/>

 <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
 <!--
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
         resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  -->
    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployOnStartup="true" deployXML="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
   </Host>
  </Engine>
</Service>
</Server>
```

I am trying this script to find some text( .*password.* ) between two strings (inclusive of strings) and then replace it with a placeholder. Whenever my cmdlinepasswd placeholder has special characters say "/" character it fails.

```
sed -ie "/$datasource/,/password*/ {s/.*password.*/\tpassword=\"$cmdlinepasswd\"/;}"    file.txt
```

assuming 
        datasource=jdbc/myDBPool1
        cmdlinepasswd=new/passwd

I am new to scripting and any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to find the resource with name of `datasource` variable and substitute its password with the content of `cmdlinepasswd` variable?

Comment: @Birei : Yes, that is the requirement. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: `sed` does this task more difficult. Is there any option of using more powerful tools, like `perl` or `python`?

Comment: @Birei: Perl would do.

Comment: sed is an excellent tool fo simple sustitutions on a single line but for any othertext processing you should be using awk. Are there literally lines with 2 dashes between each record? Please update your posted sample input to be EXACTLY what the input looks like, including what's between each record, if anything. Are you simply saying you want to change the password in records that have a specific `name` value such as `jdbc/myDBPool1`?

Comment: @EdMorton : Sorry..!! That was an alignment issue and you now have the right file.. And for your another question yes, i am just trying to change the password in the records that have a specific name value which will be read using a placeholder $datasource

Comment: @Birei: using the "i" switch gives an exception as below.[guru@localhost conf]$ perl -pie 'BEGIN { ($datasource,$cmdlinepasswd) = (shift,shift) } if ( $range = ( m/="\Q${datasource}"/ ... /password=/ ) ) {if ( q|E0| eq substr $range, -2 ) {s/(=").*("\s*)$/$1${cmdlinepasswd}$2/;} }' $datasource $cmdlinepasswd server.xml

Can't open perl script "BEGIN { ($datasource,$cmdlinepasswd) = (shift,shift) } if ( $range = ( m/="\Q${datasource}"/ ... /password=/ ) ) {if ( q|E0| eq substr $range, -2 ) {s/(=").*("\s*)$/$1${cmdlinepasswd}$2/;} }": No such file or directory

Comment: The `-i` switch is special. Following characters are the suffix of the backup file, for example: `perl -i.bak -pe '...'`. If you want to modify it in-place, leave a space after it, like: `perl -i -pe '...'` **EDIT**: Wait, why are we doing comments inside the question? Add them in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -v datasource="jdbc/myDBPool1" -v cmdlinepasswd="new/passwd" '
$0 ~ "^[[:space:]]*<Resource.*name=\"" datasource "\"" {
    sub(/password="[^"]+"/,"password=\"" cmdlinepasswd "\"")
} 1' file
```

It just looks for records that start with `<Resource` followed by `name="<your datasource variable value>"` and if it finds one it replaces the password in that record.

If you have shell variables already

```
datasource="jdbc/myDBPool1"
cmdlinepasswd="new/passwd"
```

just pass them into awk as:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -v datasource="$datasource" -v cmdlinepasswd="$cmdlinepasswd" '
$0 ~ "^[[:space:]]*<Resource.*name=\"" datasource "\"" {
    sub(/password="[^"]+"/,"password=\"" cmdlinepasswd "\"")
} 1' file
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However what if we have "name" jumbled down somewhere and resides not exactly below <Resource

Comment: @user2714227 it makes no difference, the script will work as-is.

Comment: :: Ok ED. Will check that out. Thanks for the timely Help

Comment: Hi ED. The above awk script works really well without any issues when there are no blank spaces among "name", "=" and "datasourcename" just like name="jdbc/myDBPool1"
But the real issue is when you have blank space like          <blank spaces>name <blank spaces> = <blank spaces>"jdbc/myDBPool1" then the script fails to do a search and replace. Can you kindly help me with this one.

Comment: Anywhere there could be a space, add [[:space:]]* to the RE. So, maybe instead of `"^[[:space:]]*<Resource.*name=\""` you'd want `"^[[:space:]]*<Resource.*name[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\""`. `[[:space:]]*` means `zero or more occurrences of any type of spaces`

Comment: Thanks ED.. Hope that should work.. Will check and get back to you if i run into any issues again..

Answer (score 0):

One way using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl). It accepts three arguments, the variables to check/substitute and the input file. It's better than [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) because it does quotemeta (`\Q`) to arguments, that escapes many special characters of a regex.

```
perl -pe '
    ## Get arguments but input file.
    BEGIN { ($datasource,$cmdlinepasswd) = (shift,shift) }
    ## Get a range from resource name until the line with the password.
    if ( $range = ( m/=\s*"\Q${datasource}"/ ... /password\s*=/ ) ) {
        ## "E0" points to last line (that contains the password, so
        ## change it.
        if ( q|E0| eq substr $range, -2 ) {
            s/(=\s*").*("\s*)$/$1${cmdlinepasswd}$2/;
        }
    }
' "$datasource" "$cmdlinepasswd" infile
```

With your example input data, it yields (only showed the part of the password that was modified, and left the rest untouched):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="${shutdown.port}" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

<Listener className="com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener"
        port="${jmx.port}"
        bind="127.0.0.1"
        useSSL="false"
        passwordFile="${catalina.base}/conf/jmxremote.password"
        accessFile="${catalina.base}/conf/jmxremote.access"
        authenticate="true"/>

<Listener className="com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.deploy.TcContainerDeployer" />

 <GlobalNamingResources>

 <Resource
       name="jdbc/myDBPool1"
       auth="Container"
       type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
       description="Oracle Datasource"
       factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
       url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:<dbanme>"
       user="myusername"
       password="new/passwd"
       validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
 />

...
```

**NOTE**: After see your edit, it would be a better option to use an `xml` parser, but this solution seems to work in my test.

Comment: Thank you.. This seem to be working fine. Can you please let me know how do we replace it(and save). Script is now echoing the output after the replace. Just removed the comments and used this script as. perl -pe 'BEGIN { ($datasource,$cmdlinepasswd) = (shift,shift) } if ( $range = ( m/="\Q${datasource}"/ ... /password=/ ) ) {if ( q|E0| eq substr $range, -2 ) {s/(=").*("\s*)$/$1${cmdlinepasswd}$2/;} }' $datasource $cmdlinepasswd file.xml

Comment: @user2714227: It's the same as with `sed`. The switch `-i` has same meaning for both of them.

Comment: And here is what i used. perl -i -pe 'BEGIN { ($datasource,$cmdlinepasswd) = (shift,shift) } if ( $range = ( m/="\Q${datasource}"/ ... /password=/ ) ) {if ( q|E0| eq substr $range, -2 ) {s/(=").*("\s*)$/$1${cmdlinepasswd}$2/;} }' $datasource $cmdlinepasswd server.xml

Comment: Ya with double quotes as suggested earlier.. Missed it in the above comment.

Comment: I have an interesting problem with the script now. whenever I have blank space between name and "" item like                          name    =    "jdbc/myDBPool1" the perl script fails to do a search and replace. But without any blank spaces between name and datasource like for eg: name="jdbc/myDBPool1" the script works like a charm. can you kindly help me here.

Comment: @user2714227: Yes. In regular expression use `\s` to match white spaces. I've added it in every place between the equal sign and the double quotes. Test it.

Comment: Thanks Birei.. Will check and get back to you with any issues.